# Spring Integration - stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter with out parameter only function throws " Missing IN or OUT parameter"

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to set up a poller that uses a function which returns a varchar indicating if it is time for the job to be kicked off.  I have one output parameter which I have set but it seems to be incorrect as I'm getting the following error:

```
2015-10-01 16:30:44,413 ERROR [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call FN_MY_FUNCTION()}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

I'm unsure why I'm getting this error.  Here is my adapter definition:

```
  <!-- JDBC polling channel adapter -->
  <int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter 
    auto-startup="false" 
    id="jobControlPollingChannelAdapter"
    data-source="dataSource"
    channel="outputChannel"
    expect-single-result="true"
    is-function="true"
    stored-procedure-name="${outbound.feed.db.polling.sp}"
  >

    <int:poller default="false" id="jdbcPoller" fixed-delay="5000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="completionStatus" direction="OUT" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="outboundRunCheckResult" row-mapper="outboundRunCheckMapper" />
  </int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The function call is very simple:

```
? = call FN_MY_FUNCTION()
```

Thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
? = call FN_MY_FUNCTION()
```

isn't valid syntax in this case, try:

SELECT FN_MY_FUNCTION() FROM DUAL

and get the result from the result set.

Comment: It is valid syntax. From other his db might not be Oracle.

Comment: That syntax is actually derived by Spring.  I just give it the name.  @ArtemBilan yes, the DB is Oracle.

Comment: Turns out, since my function had just 1 outbound parameter, it was easier for me to just use an `inbound-channel-adapter` and call the function this way.  So I ditched the `stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter` and poll via the function this way.

Answer (score 1):

From my side I can share with you something like this:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter id="inbound-adapter" channel="outputChannel" data-source="dataSource"
    ignore-column-meta-data="true"
    expect-single-result="true"
    stored-procedure-name="GET_RANDOM_NUMBER"
     is-function="true">
    <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="out" row-mapper="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SingleColumnRowMapper"/>
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Where the procedure is like this:

```
17:43:06,036 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 simple.SimpleJdbcCall:313 - Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{? = call GET_RANDOM_NUMBER()}]
17:43:06,037 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 simple.SimpleJdbcCall:289 - SqlCall for function [GET_RANDOM_NUMBER] compiled
17:43:06,039 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 metadata.CallMetaDataContext:500 - Matching [] with []
17:43:06,039 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 metadata.CallMetaDataContext:501 - Found match for []
17:43:06,041 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 simple.SimpleJdbcCall:395 - The following parameters are used for call {? = call GET_RANDOM_NUMBER()} with {}
17:43:06,041 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 simple.SimpleJdbcCall:398 - 1: out, SQL type 0, type name null, parameter class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlReturnResultSet]
17:43:06,042 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 core.JdbcTemplate:1062 - Calling stored procedure [{? = call GET_RANDOM_NUMBER()}]
```

If I add this:

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="out" direction="OUT" type="DECIMAL"/>
```

I see the same procedure compilation result, but now with the Exception on the call:

```
17:44:09,141 ERROR task-scheduler-1 handler.LoggingHandler:145 - org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{? = call GET_RANDOM_NUMBER()}]; ??? ??????
No data is available [2000-180]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: ??? ??????
No data is available [2000-180]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:102)
```

Yes, it is different issue, but you should see from here that your `sql-parameter-definition` is guilty.

In other word the `returning-resultset` specifies the parameter for the procedure call anyway. See the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlReturnResultSet` `SqlParameter` extension.

Let me know if it is like other way.

Comment: This looks good... I'll try it in a bit and let you know what happens.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: OK so there is definitely progress here.  Original error is now gone, but now I'm getting `2015-10-02 10:26:48,167 ERROR [task-scheduler-9] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{? = call FN_MY_FUNCTION()}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored`
Things seem to look good from the DB side so I'm wondering if there's something else wrong with my config.

Comment: M-m-m. Is it really function on the Oracle side? Would you mind sharing its definition? From other side how does it work with the `ignore-column-meta-data="true"` on the adapter definition?

Comment: Does your function really return `Cursor` (`SELECT .... FROM ....`)? For the `returning-resultset`, I mean. Maybe you really have there just only single `OUT` param... Than it really would be better to change your config to the `<jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="RESULT_CODE" type="NUMERIC" direction="OUT"/>` instead...

Comment: Yes it is a function and the definition is with just one output parameter.  I'm thinking it was the `ignore-column-meta-data="true"` that got me past the initial issue.  I was trying it with the `sql-parameter-definition` as you described already and that's what I didn't understand.  I set up the one out parameter and it still wasn't working.  The poller was originally a query and the logic behind it changed so we moved it to a function.  As it turns out, the easiest thing to do was actually leave it as a `inbound-channel-adapter` and call the function as a query as @Miner_Glitch suggested.

Comment: Yes, that is another way to invoke simple functions. And I'd say it is better from Java perspective: we don't interact with PL_SQL engine there - just `PreparedStatement`!